# How to convert image to text?

Tags: php, web

Hello im just wondering if I can covert or read a text in an image after upload . In web based , im actually want to upload photo where if I upload it it automatically read or check and image if their is a text or not. For example I upload a picture of ID and It will identify if it is a School ID, Voters ID and Etc.

Thankyou so much any answer will be appreciated Thankyouu!

Comment: I am not sure about a direct approach for extract text from Image. You need to write some extracting algorithm for this or you can use some online tools. Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou sir. I really appreciate the idea